# How to validate Dictionary in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

**ViewModels**

```
[Display(Name = "Purchase limit")]
[Required]
public Dictionary<int, int> DownloadLimit { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
@foreach (var downloadLimit in Model.DownloadLimit)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DownloadLimit[downloadLimit.Key], new { @class = "form-control mb10", @type = "number"})
}
```

My dictionary have key and value both is integer. When I input a string to textbox, message error was show: "The field Int32 must be a number".

1. How could i custom this message to "The download limit must be a number"
2. How could i add RangeAttribute to validate all values must be in the specific range.

RangeAttribute not working in Dictionary.
I have tried:

```
[Range(0,99999999, ErrorMessage = "Download Limit must be a number in range from 0 to 99999999")]
public Dictionary<int, int> DownloadLimit { get; set; }
```

Anyone could suggest me the way to do that, i am highly enjoy to a solution that not using custom attribute.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
 [Range(typeof(int), "0", "9999", ErrorMessage = "{0} must be a decimal/number between {1} and {2}.")]
```

or

```
[Range(typeof(decimal), "0", "9999", ErrorMessage = "{0} must be a decimal/number between {1} and {2}.")]
```

Comment: Thanks @Saravanan! In many research, i founded that the best solution is using custom annotation to validate Dictionary on ViewModel. Thanks for your recommendation.